# ngAnimate ng-enter to animate child elements

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I am trying to animate multiple elements within each ui-view as the user navigates from view to view.

I was hoping I could leverage the ui-view.ng-enter and ui-view.ng-leave to make this happen. For example:

```
ui-view.ng-enter, ui-view.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: 1000ms ease-in-out all;
  transition: 1000ms ease-in-out all;
}

ui-view.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;

  #register, #login, #forgot-pass {
    -webkit-transition: 500ms ease-out all;
    transition: 500ms ease-out all;

    margin-top: -100px;
  }
}
ui-view.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;

  #register, #login, #forgot-pass {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}

ui-view.ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;

  #register, #login, #forgot-pass {
    -webkit-transition: 500ms ease-in all;
    transition: 500ms ease-in all;

    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}
ui-view.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;

  #register, #login, #forgot-pass {
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
}
```

But while the ui-view's opacity is animating, the child element is not.
Has anyone tinkered with this in the past and has it worked?

Any alternative approaches that work would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: is this css? i am not sure we can nest it like this

Comment: this is pseudo code, in less or sass, so we sure can.

Comment: @Stefan you should be able to, there is no reason not to... Do you mind showing the actual css code you're using ?

Comment: I gave up on it late last night, strangely enough it seemed to work on ng-leave/ng-leave-active but not on ng-enter/ng-enter-active. I cant get my head around it.

I will update the code above with something very close to what I was working on doing.

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Updated the code quickly so there may be a couple of mistakes, but you get the point.

Interesting to note, if the transition timing on the ui-view is set to something lower than that of all the child element transitions, they simply get cut off.

That seems weird to me since the animations should be queued up regardless of their parent but I guess that I am wrong on that.

Comment: Try adding the attribute `ng-animate-children` on the element with the main ui-view.

Comment: Hey, Stafan. I'm having the same problem here. Have you found a solution for this?